# Do homologous chromosomes have same rates of gene expression in a cell?

Tags: cell-biology, gene-expression, chromosome, gene, homology

I was googling around and found only articles related to XY differences in expression. Can you please clarify if homologous genes/chromosomes have about the same levels of expression in a cell or one of them "stays silent" and another is "switched on" somehow?

Comment: It's a complicated subject. Try searching for "genetic imprinting" and also for "epigenetics" and for "gene regulation in cis and trans".

Comment: thanks for a feedback! Everything is a complicated subject, I'm a software engineer by the way ;)